# My server shows around 30-40 GB of download (rx) per day: because of `mdns` or `netbios-ns`?

Tags: networking, server, mdns

For several days now my server logs a huge amount of download traffic this is unusual. This traffic is constant, about 100-200 KB/s from IP addresses that are registered under the same data center.

After digging into details I faced this.

Real-time traffic monitor (`iftop`)

[image: image of iftop]

Can you explain what are these and how can I stop them? I have limited bandwidth and this traffic sums up to about 1-2 GB per hour.

My Installed packages: https://pastebin.com/1DYiRxne

Working processes: https://pastebin.com/iRwatj8z

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @David 20.04.5 LTS

Comment: Doing a whois on those IP addresses is ...not comforting.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I did, all of what I tested was for the provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was a package problem or something

after upgrading Nginx and some other packages, the mysterious traffic gone